# How can I check if an element is not undefined with a hidden-block in Angular HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, hidden

how can I check if an element is not undefined with a hidden-block, i.e.
how can I write the following code with a hidden-block

```
 <div class="timeSlot" *ngIf="timeSlot.track">
```

I tried something like this

```
   <div class="timeSlot" [hidden]="!timeSlot?.track">
```

but it's not the same.

I hope somebody can help.

THX

Comment: I want something like this <div class="timeSlot" [hidden]="timeSlot.track === undefined">. But it doesn't work.

Comment: oh wow, I found the solution. The error is in  "class="timeSlot"  " I remove it and it worked. Tank's!

Answer (score 0):

In alternative you can try to use shorthand inside hidden directive:

```
<div class="timeSlot" [hidden]="timeSlot.track === undefined ? true : false">
```

Answer (score -1):

### In HTML File

```
<div class="timeSlot" [hidden]="isHidden()">
```

### In .ts File

```js
isHidden() {
if(this.timeSlot.track === undefined) {
 return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the above code

Comment: The div block is always displayed, independently if track is undefined or not. Also with the solution with the hidden() method

Comment: Can you please make your question clear